# How to assign TextField Delegate and methods when creating reusable views

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, delegates

I am trying to create a reusable UI Component within my app, this particular component contains a UITextFeild. I have successfully set up the text field in the view and it displays perfectly, however... The text fields delegate setup doesn't work.

I have tried referencing the text field from the created object like so

```
let sessionNameCell = ReusableComponents().createTextFieldCell()
sessionNameCell.textField.delegate = self
```

But cannot reference the text field from the controller.

I have also tried setting the delegate multiple ways inside of the function that creates the view:

```
textField.delegate = self
```

and

```
textField.delegate = ViewController()
```

the last one crashed the app, as I understand creating an instance of the object is not a suitable solution

The full code is...

View Controller

```
class HostSessionSetupController : UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

private var sessionNameCell: UITableViewCell = ReusableComponents().createEditableTableRow(title: "Session Name", placeholder: "e.g. Marks birthday")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sessionNameCell.textField.delegate = self

}

// The delegate method i need to run
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    if let input = textField.text {
        if input != ""{
            self.title = "Setup " + input
        } else {
            self.title = "Setup Session"
        }
    }
}
```

View Function

```
func createTableRow(title: String, accessoryType: UITableViewCell.AccessoryType = .none) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.backgroundColor = .backgroundDarkBlack
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    cell.textLabel?.text = title
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.accessoryType = accessoryType

    return cell
}

func createEditableTableRow(title: String, placeholder: String) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = createTableRow(title: title)
    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x:  40, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height))

    textField.textColor = .white
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.init(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)])
    textField.keyboardAppearance = .dark
    textField.returnKeyType = .default
    textField.textAlignment = .right

    cell.addSubview(textField)

    return cell

}
```

The only functionality I'm trying to get from all this is to hide the keyboard on keyboard return! D:

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate of the TextField when you create the cell